# Heroku push fails due to failure to compile Firefox app

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to deploy an app to Heroku, but some errors stand in my way. (I am totally new to this, so please bear with me if I am using some terms incorrectly).

My app is a single python file that scrapes some data from a webpage using Selenium (don't care if there are better alternatives for this, that's beside the point).

I did everything correctly (I assume), by adding the necessary buildpacks to my app (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python | https://github.com/pyronlaboratory/heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver | http://github.com/buitron/firefox-buildpack), but when I try to push to Heroku using 'git push heroku master', I am getting hit with this:

```
remote: -----> firefox app detected
remote: -----> Fetching Firefox package from https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-SSL&os=linux64&lang=en-US
remote: -----> Extracting Firefox binaries to /tmp/build_b78d320b/vendor/firefox
remote: mv: cannot move '/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/firefox' to '/tmp/build_b78d320b/vendor/firefox': Directory not empty
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile firefox app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to hydrogen-gas.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/hydrogen-gas.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hydrogen-gas.git'
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include the error as text and not as an image.  I'm a little confused with what you're doing as you seem to have ```mv /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/firefox /tmp/build_b785320b/vendor/firefox```; but the destination directory was just created by the previous file extraction.  Are you sure you have the ```mv``` command right?

Comment: @ewong I did not write the 'mv' command if that's what you meant. Everything you see in the image is done automatically after I try to push the changes to the remote repo with 'git push heroku master'.